# How to pass a Date in url param and how to validate it with class-validator?

Tags: api, rest, nestjs, class-validator

I'm trying to validate a date param (with class-validator) in my Nest.js api; below is what I have:

```
class DateValidate {
  @IsDate()
  date: Date;
}
```

```
  @Get('day/:day')
  getDayMealsPlan(@Param('day') day: DateValidate): any {
    return day;
  }
```

I'm passing the date param in the URL like so:

```
localhost:3000/meals/day/2022-03-06T11:00:00.000Z
```

It's throwing me a 400 error:

```
{
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": [
        "date must be a Date instance"
    ],
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```

I have a 2 part question:

1. How to validate a date?
2. How would a date look in the param? Is this the right way to do it: 2022-03-06T11:00:00.000Z

Comment: by using `@Param('day') day: DateValidate` you're telling that `day` is a object with `date` prop in it, but `req.params.day` isn't, that's why you're getting 400

Comment: So how should I be doing this so that it validates the Date properly. And how would I pass it in the url param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`2022-03-06T11:00:00.000Z` this value is a String type. That's why class-validator is complaining `not Date instance`.

You need to tell to transform your string format to Date.

You can achieve that using `Type` decorator from `class-transformer`.

```js
class DateValidate {
  @IsDate()
  @Type(() => Date)
  day: Date;
}
```

```js
@Controller('something')
export class SomethingController {
  @Get('day/:day')
  getDayMealsPlan(@Param() params: DateValidate) {
    console.log(params.day instanceof Date); // true
    return params;
  }
}
```

Comment: I see, so when it comes in the url param, it's always a string and you'll have to change it to the type you want to validate. Thanks, your solution worked :)

Answer (score -1):

I believe it should be:

```js
@Get('day/:date') // <
getDayMealsPlan(@Param() o: DateValidate): any {
  return o.date
}
```

Comment: That gives me the same error unfortunately

Comment: Did you just repeat what comment above yours said?